# How to implement PDFViewerApplication and PDFViewerApplicationOptions in ng2-pdfjs-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer, pdfjs-dist

Am using ng2-pdfjs-viewer in my ANGULAR site to view PDF. But my client requested to add some More Site Related links in the toolbar like Contact Us, Navigate to some other site. I thought we can use PDFViewerApplication and PDFViewerApplicationOptions.

Can someone let me how can I implement PDFViewerApplication and PDFViewerApplicationOptions? Or please suggest to me some other options?

Comment: were you successful in exposing PDFViewerAppplication and ApplicationOptions, i have a similar kind of requirement and need to build custom viewer using angular. any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use both configuration you need to first create reference to 'PdfJsViewerComponent' maybe using viewchild as,

> @ViewChild(PdfJsViewerComponent) public PdfJsViewerComponent: PdfJsViewerComponent;

and then above properties can be used to access or modify existing features as:

> this.PdfJsViewerComponent.PDFViewerApplication.(name of any available property)

Also to add any extra content on top of viewer, you can use style `position: absolute` and relocate contents.

Also to add any extra content dynamically over pdf/images, canvas can be used. Where the (X,Y) position set to locate element.

Comment: pdfjs dist folder doesnt have PDFViewerapplication module , could you please let us know how can we include other modules such as PDFViewerApplication,PDFViewerApplicationOptions,cursor tools , annotations etc.